# How much time do I need to wait for an Italian passport?

Tags: passports, italy, italian-citizens

I'm an Italian citizen , and i planned to travel to Thailand (Phuket) around July.
I'm not a beginner traveller, but I only travelled around Europe.
I bought the plane ticket, bought hotel and so on , when I suddenly remembered I need a passport(Europe has made me used to thinking that I  only needed ID ).

How much time does it take more or less to obtain a passport in Italy? is it generally more or less than 2 months?  Am I still able to perform this trip or I should move to the "refund option"?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if it takes more than a few weeks, and most countries have an expedited (fast/urgent) option if you pay more.

Comment: In fact here in Sydney, Australia, it's possible for Italians to get a passport on the same day (http://www.conssydney.esteri.it/consolato_sydney/resource/doc/2016/03/how_to__italian_passport.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really depends on where you live and how busy the Questura is.
You can [register online](https://www.passaportonline.poliziadistato.it/logInCittadino.do) for an appointment, then you must present in person.
An officer will scan your fingerprints and gather the required documents.
You can find a list of required documents [here](http://www.poliziadistato.it/articolo/10301).

There's a fee of € 42,50 plus a "Marca da Bollo" stamp of € 73,50.

It will take about 2 weeks during non-busy periods. (personal experience)

**Edit after comment**:
Well then, looks like in Milan you can ask for [urgent processing](http://questure.poliziadistato.it/servizio/orari/5730dc9d1c2b6663551681) of your application only for health or work issues.
Immigration office seems separate from Passport office, that's good news.

Comment: Assuming i'm from Milano, and summer is coming...i'm not gonna have a good experience...

Comment: @Anon You may be lucky as offices are separate (refugees applications should not slow passport applications). If you hurry and register online *now* you may be able to get your passport in time

Answer (score 1):

If you get the Italian Citizen, the total time is no more than 6 weeks (1 month and a half). So, I believe you will not spend more than that. 
I got this information from [here](http://www.italiamerica.org/id71.htm#23).